# Node inspector doesn't stop on break points

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

[image]I am trying to debug a node application, I have placed break point in chrome://inspect. But I am surprised on starting node application it doesn't stop at that break point.

I have ran these commands node --inspect app.js then chrom://inspect to set break points[image]

Comment: did you run the command `node debug <your filename>.js`

Comment: I tried this now, I still don't debug point not getting paused or I am not sure what to do in the terminal